# sockets accept CPU usage to 100%

Tags: linux, sockets

I have a simple app which opens a socket and waits for a connection using the accept() function.

On one hand, when I run this app on a ASRock SBC-210 mother board (processor = Celeron J1900, Ethernet Controller =  Realtek RTL8111G-CG), processors are mostly unused (few percent when running several application instances)

On the other hand, running this app on a AAEON GENE-BT05 (processor = Celeron N2930, Ethernet controller = Intel I210AT or I211 AT), each instance of application uses a CPU at 100%...

The issue clearly comes from the accept() function.

It seems that the accept() function polls on the AAEON (intel gbi module) and thus the problem is is due to the driver.

How can I check this ? 
Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code, preferably the simplest code needed to replicate the problem.

Comment: Sorry but it was an error of us !!. I tried to make a simple example containing only the appropriate code and could not reproduce the issue. I then dig into the source code and saw that a thread was adding and this thread...polls to detect events !! once the creation of this thread commented, all works as expected.. Seems that the a external lib is not the same on the 2 devices !!!